# Chalenging nodejs CSV to JSON parsing problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, parsing

I'm currently faced with a specific problem.
I have to parse CSV file to the JSON, and usually csv-parser works well, however, this time I have received a CSV file with terrible separators:
[image: terrible separators]

The lines look like

```
val||"val"||"val"||"val"
```

The question is how do you think it is possible to go through all CSV lines and change all the "||" to simple comas?

Here is my code for parsing:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const csv = require('csv-parser')

// Read CSV and Write to the JSON

const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('./CSV/users-test.csv')
  .pipe(csv({separator: '||'}))
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {      
      console.log(results);
      fs.writeFileSync('./OutputJSON/data.json', JSON.stringify(results),'utf-8', (err) => {
          if (err) console.log('That is bad')
      })
  });
```

And here is what I get in the JSON:
[image: Broken JSON]

It works when all user's data are separated by ',' but I have no idea how to find and replace all that "||" in the CSV file before I parse it.

Comment: You are almost there. Have a look at [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Note, that if applied to the whole input text, it will replace every occurence in it.

Answer (score 1):

csv-parser only allows one-character delimiters. You can preprocess your incoming file into lines with [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream) and then remove the nasty field separators.  Something like this ... not debugged.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const es = require('event-stream')

const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('./CSV/users-test.csv')
  .pipe(es.split())             // line by line
  .pipe(es.replace('||','|')    // turn || into |
  .pipe(csv({separator: '|'}))  // handle CSV with | separator
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {      
      console.log(results);
      fs.writeFileSync('./OutputJSON/data.json', JSON.stringify(results),'utf-8', (err) => {
          if (err) console.log('That is bad')
      })
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, however, making it this way returns only [ ] - to the JSON file. For some reason, it does not push data to the array.

Comment: after I comment .pipe(es.split())   - the code works same as in the question, but with .pipe(es.split())  it returns anly [ ] that are in the const results = [];